# Is there a way to cast a result in EL?

Tags: java, jsf, el

I have JSF page that is trying to call a method in my managed bean, but is throwing an error that I am calling an ambiguous method:

```
<div class="Container100 MarTop5 #{surveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass(cc.attrs.multiChoiceItem.answer)}">
```

The error is:

```
SEVERE: /resources/component/checkMany2.xhtml: Unable to find unambiguous method: class org.beans.questionnaire.SurveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass(null)
javax.el.ELException: /resources/component/checkMany2.xhtml: Unable to find unambiguous method: class org.beans.questionnaire.SurveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass(null)
```

The problem is that my SurveyBean class has overloaded `getBackGroundStyleClass()` methods.  Consequently, when the `cc.attrs.multiChoiceItem.answer` is null, it does not know which method to call.

In standard Java, I would be able to cast the answer to the type I want to ensure that Java can find the correct method.

How can I do this in EL?  Is it feasible?  I've tried:

but that failed miserably:

```
Failed to parse the expression [#{surveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass((Answer)cc.attrs.multiChoiceItem.answer)}]
```

I also tried:
    #{surveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass(Answer.class.cast(cc.attrs.multiChoiceItem.answer))}

but that too failed with:

```
javax.el.ELException: The identifier [class] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

Is there some way in EL to cast the argument type?

Comment: You can set the type of the attr in your composite component interface

Comment: @kukeltje. Unfortunately, the way they designed this, it isn't the attribute that is null.  It's a value retrieved from the within the attribute object.  Ie: the attribute is multiChoiceItem, but it's its  getAnswer() method that returns null.

Comment: why don't you use distinct method names?

Comment: if it is a legacy system, use a proxy managed bean with distinct method names and delegate the call to the original ones by cast parameter values.

Comment: Another option is to register a custom EL function for casting: `#{surveyBean.getBackGroundStyleClass(x:cast(cc.attrs.multiChoiceItem.answer, 'com.example.Answer'))}`